# Eclipse Plugin : how to modify a file source programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to build my first Eclipse Plugin (under Indigo). I created a Popup Menu, and I manage to get the selected File path.

My aim is to add a member and a method via the plugin, inside the class definition.

Should I parse the file myself or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the eclipse help how to manipulate Java files with the JDT --> http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm